# Remove color with Fuzzy Select Tool (hard edge)

Tags: google-earth, gimp

I have a Google Earth Image imported in Gimp and I want to remove the water from the image. I use the fuzzy select tool to mark all the water which I want to remove. But as I erase the water, a bit of the landside also gets erased. Is there a possibility to erase it so I can get a hard edge?[image: Erase color with fuzzy select tool]

Comment: This is a programming Q&A site. I suggest you visit http://gimpforums.com/ instead...

Comment: Or maybe SuperUser - although there it will also be requir^wappreciated if you have done your homework (reading docs, forums, telling what you have tried) first.